Do we have better bounds than $n^{-n}$ on the maximum ellipsoid in a unit-volume convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
By a theorem of Fritz John, we know that a compact convex body $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of nonempty interior contains a unique maximal ellipsoid $E$, sometimes called the John ellipsoid, such that $E\subseteq K \subseteq nE$. If $K$ is centrally symmetric, we have $K \subseteq \sqrt nE$.
This implies that the volume of the maximal ellipsoid is at most $\frac{\text{vol}(K)}{n^n}$, but clearly this bound is not tight, since $K$ cannot occupy all the volume of $nE$ without being able to fit a much larger ellipsoid inside. One could easily improve this bound by an argument like the following:

Apply an affine transformation such that $E$ is the ball of unit radius. WLOG, $K$ must contact $E$ at the point $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and so is bounded by the half-space $x_1\le 1$ as well as by the boundary of $nE$. Thus the volume of $K$ is at most the volume of an $n$-spherical cap of depth $n+1$ on a ball of radius $n$, which is [some complicated integral]. Dividing, we conclude that $\text{vol}(E)/\text{vol}(K)$ is at least [some expression which approaches $2\cdot n^{-n}$ for large $n$].

Of course by further careful consideration of contact points of $K$ on $E$ (which John's theorem helpfully characterizes) we could do much better than doubling this bound. What are the best known results? Are there conjectured or known optimal bodies? My first guess would be that the simplices (which are affinely equivalent and hence all achieve the same ratio) are optimal.
(I'm also interested in this question for the centrally symmetric case, and how much we can improve on a bound of $n^{-n/2}$ there.)
Even the $n=2$ case seems interesting, and I would be curious for references to literature on the problem for planar convex sets - my guess would be that that triangles achieve the worst case with $\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}9$, but I don't have any citations for this claim or see an obvious proof.
